# switching activity comes to error

Tags: android, android-activity, switch-statement

i have a problem with my project in switching activity.
mt project contain 3 activity with 3 different layout, so one activity for one layout.
but, the project can't be run and emulator says "The Application myProject has stopped unexpectedly"

this is my code:

```
public class myProject extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

     Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
     loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), login.class);
                 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
             }

     });

     Button joinButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.join);
     joinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), register.class);
                 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
             }

     });

     Button exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
     exitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 System.exit(0);
             }

     });
}
```

and here is te AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="myProject.app"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".login"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".main"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".register"></activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

please help me to find what is wrong. thank you.

UPDATE AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="myProject.app"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".myProject"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".choosepet"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".login"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".petMain"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".register"></activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

i've update and still can't be run in emulator.

UPDATE 2

i try to delete all listener and look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.myProject_layout);

 }
```

and the project run smoothly. i think the error is in button listener. can someone help to fix it?

error in logcat:

```
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tamagochi.app/tamagochi.app.tamagochi}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at tamagochi.app.tamagochi.onCreate(tamagochi.java:18)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
10-24 11:41:08.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(644):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What error are you getting in logcat when it closes?

Comment: i've mention it above. "The Application myProject has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." and a single button marked "Force Close"

Comment: Yes, but you'll get a more specific error that includes the line number in your code where the error occurs in the log output. In any case, I've pointed out exactly where your problem is in my answer below.

Comment: That alert dialog won't specify your errors in details. You'd better to post the logcat(In eclipse, switch to "DDMS" perspective to see the logcat) so we can help.

Comment: i am sorry @goto10, i don't know logcat is in DDMS. i've post the logcat.

Comment: @user1008497 you are having problem in your layout xml file check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your xml file I guess.

You are using ListView whose id is a custom one`(android:id="@+id/myListView" - something like this)` given by you that is wrong. If you are giving your own id to a ListView you have to extend your class by Activity not by ListActivity and find the id of the ListView and perform the action on it.

In your case you should use ListView's id as `android:id="@android:id/list"` when you are extending the class by ListActivity.

If you are extending the class by Activity - `android:id="@+id/myListView"`.
Else if you are using ListActivity  -  `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity class is named myProject while the name for your main activity is ".main". You also list ".main" twice in your manifest.

Remove the second reference to ".main" and make sure that the activity names in your manifest match the class names of your activities.

Like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".myProject"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".login"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".register"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: i've changed it and it still error and there's no error in console. if you don't mind can i ask for ur email so i can send my project to be check by you? @goto10

Comment: I'm sorry, but my weekend is coming to a close and won't have free time to look at your project. I would update the question with the current version of your manifest with any changes you've made and get the error from logcat according to the instructions provided by @Huang

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't post your layout xml file,i want to ask,are you sure,you need to use ListActivity? Please have a look to the basic idea of the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032417/android-activity-vs-listactivity-which-one-should-my-activity-class-extend) And also try Acitivity in place of ListActivity in your project. Your logcat shows something related to this in first line.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declared the activities in your program's xml manifest. If they aren't your program will crash ever time

Comment: i've done it. i am sure it's declared in AndroidManifest.xml, but still crash.